# Missing data in repeated measure model

Tags: matlab, mixed-models

I am using the matlab function [fitrm](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrm.html?refresh=true) to fit repeated measures model in order to investigate whether elements grouped according to Grouping1 have statistically different means for the variable measured at time t1,t2,t3,t4 (var_t1,var_t2,var_t3,var_t4).

My data look like the ones in the table:

```
Grouping1   Grouping2     Gender     Age       BMI       var_t1           var_t2          var_t3        var_t4
______    ___________    ______    ______    ______    ____________    ____________    ____________    ____________

C           B             Male       60       24.802    836             608             746             NaN         
C           A             Male       67       19.818    242             544             460             483         
...       ...
D           C             Female     65       21.631    621             468             NaN             NaN
```

As you can see from I have some missing data for var_t3 and var_t4.
Can I still use fitrm?

If fit a repeated measures model, where var_t1,-var_t4 are the responses and Grouping1, Grouping2, Gender, Age and BMI are the predictor variables

```
Time = [1:4]';    
rm = fitrm(table,'var_t1-var_t4 ~ Grouping1 + Grouping2 + Gender + Age + BMI','WithinDesign',Time)
```

the function doesn't return error, but I don't know if the results have any meaning...